# How to structure redux for List with subcategories?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning redux.

I have a list of items with its categories with different routes, say

- All Tasks
- My Tasks
- Team Tasks

**All tasks** are loaded when app loads. Now, when a user deletes a task in **My Tasks** category, then it should also be deleted from **All Tasks** category. Each category will also have search and load more functionality too.

How should I structure this in redux ?

Comment: Do you really need to store all the tasks in the redux store ? Using redux doesn't mean that you should store all the backend data in it.

Comment: I know. I am not storing all data, thats why I mentioned, there will be load more funcationality too.